# ElasticSearch updating documents in an automated way

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I don't know how to ask questions about my current problem so I think, that is why I couldn't find the right answer. So please let me tell you what my problem is.

I am trying to do a simple internet port scanner by using Zmap and Zgrab like Shodan.io,like censys.io etc.

I need to store the data inside of the ElasticSearch(because I want to learn how to use it).

In this case;

I have created a JSON architecture to use it in ElasticSearch such as

```
{
    "value": "192.168.0.1",
    "port": [
      {
        "value": 80,
        "HTMLbody": "BODY OF THE WEB PAGE",
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
          "content_type": "html/png",
          "content_length": 23123,
          "...": "..."
        },
        "certificate": {
          "company_names": [
            "example.com",
            "acme.io"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

There will be approximately 4 billion IP address inside of the Elasticsearch with different ports open. My problem begins here; After first initial scan, I need to update the exist IP addresses.

For example;

IP: 192.168.0.1
port: 80 open

When in the second scan, I scan port 443 and It will be probably open too. Then I need to update my Elasticsearch document depends on the open ports.

#### What I found so far

There is an endpoint I found which is; `POST /<index>/_update/<_id>` but it updates a single document. I need to update at least more than 100.000 document in one scan. And it should be automatically too. How do I know that an ip address document id and update it ?

Also secondly, I found;

`POST <index>/_update_by_query`

I thought about searching the ip address by using query and gathering its index number and then updating the document as follows;

```
{

    "value": "192.168.0.1",
    "port": [
      {
        "value": 80,
        "HTMLbody": "BODY OF THE WEB PAGE",
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
          "content_type": "html/png",
          "content_length": 23123,
          "...": "..."
        },
        "certificate": {
          "company_names": [
            "example.com",
            "acme.io"
          ]
        }
      },

      {
        "value": 443,
        "HTMLbody": "BODY OF THE SSL WEB PAGE",
        "status": 200
      }
    ]
}
```

In theory, I could do this but in practice couldn't write the code as efficient. Because I had at least 6 GB JSON file for one scan and it takes so long to process the whole file and updating elasticsearch.

Is there any way that solve this problem efficiently ?

[Please Look the image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxSmO.png)

Comment: Do you try [Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) ? You can add multiple queries, like update or index, and it is simple to use in the code. You just need to correctly build your documents to be updated and make sure the mapping is correct. Which language are you using to do this ?

Comment: I am using Python for it. I saw Bulk API but I don't know exact index id of the every ip address so how can I update it by using Bulk API ?

 I am very very new for ElasticSearch maybe I didn't understand the logic of Bulk API

Comment: Can you look at the image at bottom of my post ? It is exactly what I need but I don't know about the arrangement of the index ID's inside of the Elasticsearch. In this case how to update proper documents without knowing its ID number ?

Comment: If I understand, each document represent one ip adresse, and you want to update document when a new port is up for one ip adress ? Why you don't use the ip adresse as `_id` ? In that way, you can easily define which document to update and build your update queries. For the bulk part, imagine that is an array, you add some queries in this array, and at the end, you execute all this array of queries, and the bulk api will do this efficiently.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think about the using ip address as _id. This maybe small idea for you but will help me a lot , thank you so much  !

My last problem is; As far as I know the Elasticsearch documents are immutable. It means that it deletes the existing document and creating new document with the updated parts. 

In this case; Do I need to know the exact status of the json file ? How to add information below the exist information ? For example the Json file top of the post. How can I add 443 port to it by using bulk api ? I am afraid of overwriting the existing data.

Comment: If I were you, I would store one document per IP/port (with `_id: 192.168.0.1-80`) that way you don't need to update anything, you just keep indexing as you scan ports on different IP addresses. You can definitely index a new version of a document on top of an existing one (i.e. same IP/port combo)

Comment: @Val, But I don't have much storage and RAM capacity and the data will continiously grow in that way. If we can think of the avarage of every ip can have 4 open ports, It will become more than 16 billion documents. This will not efficient I guess. If I can find a way to add JSON object as update to a document. I am going to complete the project. I feel I am so close !

Comment: It makes not big difference to have 4 independent documents instead of one document with those 4 documents nested into it. Mind you, it's even less performant to use nested documents in such a case, because you'd not only end up using more space (4 nested + 1 root document) but the queries will also be much less flexible and less performant and when you'll need to update a nested document, you'll need to have complicated logic that figures out which "port" nested document you need to replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fully answer to the question, first, use the ip adress as `_id` to make sur to update the appropriate document.
You need to add an entry in the port array, so use the `_update` API to perform it like this :

```
POST <index>/_update/192.168.0.1
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.port.add(params.tag)",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "tag": {
        "value": 443,
        "HTMLbody": "BODY OF THE SSL WEB PAGE",
        "status": 200
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is an [update query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) to add an entry to an array with a little script.

To use the bulk, simply add all of your request like explained [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)

Comment: Thank you, but now I have a little bit different problem. This is the way I can update the values. But I need to add JSON Objects inside of the Port[] array.  I have searched a little bit but I couldn't find an answer about updating fields by adding new objects.

Comment: The values uner `tag` is a jsonobject, it should word as expected. My answer include the json you put as example, but I make a mistake, in the `source` instruction, I've edited my answer to make it work!

Comment: It worked like it is magic. You are the number one of my "This Month Heroes" list !